# Kohana3 ORM sum() equivalent

Tags: select, count, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I need the equivalent of

```
SELECT SUM(balance) as "total_balance" FROM users;
```

in Kohana3.

So, how to find a sum of the `balance` column  of `users` table in Kohana3?

```
$total_balance = ORM::factory ( 'user' )->find ();//I want to change this string to find total_balance to be a sum of the balance column.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no `SUM()` equivalent in ORM. Kohana ORM doesn't provides much equivalents to native SQL functions.

As a workaround use `DB::select()` with `DB::expr()` like:

```
$total_balance = DB::select(array(DB::expr('SUM(`balance`)'), 'total_balance'))
    ->from('users')
    ->execute()
    ->get('total_balance');
```

Produced query:

```
SELECT SUM(`balance`) AS `total_balance` FROM `users`
```

Comment: You can also use: `DB::select(array('SUM("balance")', 'total_balance))` or similar. Note the double quotes