# Optimizing: Total with query and not php code

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I am in need of grabbing some stats from a 88k rows table.

The rows are each representing a reference number, which are connected to a order in the system. One order can have multiple reference numbers.

Now I would like to archieve to find out some totales, how many claimed reference numbers are there, and how many cancelled reference numbers are there - and group and list the totales per Deal.

This is what I have done: (OBS. Kohana Query Builder are used for the queries, but I think you can figure out what the real MySQL query look like. And you can answer in pure MySQL query)

```
    $refs = DB::select('refnumbers.cancelled', 'refnumbers.is_claimed', 'deals.price', 'deals.ID', 'refnumbers.order_id')
    ->from('refnumbers')
    ->join('deals')->on('deals.ID', '=', 'refnumbers.deal_id')
    ->execute()
    ->as_array();

    $total_cancelled = array();
    $total_claimed = array();

    foreach($refs as $ref)
    {
        $isProduct = DB::select('product_id')->from('orders_chosenoptions')->where('order_id', '=', $ref['order_id'])->execute()->get('product_id', 0);

        if($isProduct > 0)
        {
            $price = DB::select('price')->from('deals_products')->where('id', '=', $isProduct)
            ->execute()->get('price', $ref['price']);

        }else{
            $price = $ref['price'];
        }

        if($ref['cancelled'] == 1)
        {
            $total_cancelled[$ref['ID']] += $price;
        }else if($ref['is_claimed'] == 1)
        {
            $total_claimed[$ref['ID']] += $price;
        }
    }
```

I believe that all this code can maybe be replaced by a query? Maybe with some SUM(deals.price) if cancelled = 1 (i dont know how to do this in pure mysql) and the same to is_claimed.

There is just one more 'problem' which is that we can not trust the deals.price if the deal that the user have bought is a product deal and there's different prices inside the deal - then we need to grab the price from deals_products as you can see.

Is it possible to do it all in one query? If not, how can this php code be optimized?

Since this code will take forever and probably time out (even with a high timeout setting) with these 88k rows, I seek for a solution like this.

Thanks

Comment: The Kohana ORM should be able to give an aggregate (e.g. SUM). have you checked the documentation?

Comment: Check for aggregates in your ORM. In particular for `sum`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Kohana3 ORM sum() equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456450/kohana3-orm-sum-equivalent)

Comment: I know I can do DB::expr('SUM(deals.price)') with Kohana, but with just that, It will not sum correct. Please read further

Comment: I'm having problem since I would like the query to 1) have some IF and then it should SUM() and 2) grab the product price if necessary